# Need search list as popover in ionic 3

Tags: html, angular, typescript

This is my html code

```
<ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="data" placeholder="Airlines" (ionInput)="getAirlines($event)">
  </ion-searchbar>
  <ion-list *ngIf="data">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of airlines" (click)="airlinesClicked($event, item)">
      <button ion-button item-start clear style="margin-right:2%;  width:10%;height:10%" no-padding>
        <img no-padding src="{{item.logo}}">
      </button>
      {{item.name}}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Iam trying to get searched result as list by filtering by each letters. While i am searching my list pushing my below contents down in my page. So i like to get my item as popover. Can anyone help me to get my result......
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not pretty sure but maybe when the data is ready you can create a popover controller and the resize the page.

```
import { PopoverController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({})
class yourClassName {
   constructor(public PopOverCtrl: PopoverController) {}

   presentPopover(event) {
      let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(ListPage);
      popover.present({
         ev: event
   });

  }
}
```

more details on [Ionic website](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/popover/PopoverController/)

Comment: i tried this one as popover. if i am searching by full name it will okay, but i m using search by each letter. the list want to load by filtering by typing each letters.

Comment: Have you tried to return your getAirliness() method Observables? at past I made auto complete search component with Firebase list observables, maybe you can search about observables.

Comment: getAirlines(ev: any){
      this.airlines = this.airlinesItems

      let val = ev.target.value;
      
          // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
          if (val && val.trim() != '') {
            this.airlines = this.airlines.filter((item) => {
              return (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
            })
          }
    }

Comment: What about this one;
getAirlines(ev: any).subscribe(flight => {
      //filter then this.airlines = flight;
})

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap for the following class tags
and create a custom list popover on ion-searchbar

```
<ion-row>
        <ion-searchbar
          (ionChange)="getAirlines($event)"
           [(ngModel)]="data" placeholder="Airlines"
        ></ion-searchbar>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row>
        <ul
          class="list-group position-absolute px-2 search-list w-100 rounded-2 shadow-sm"
          *ngIf="data">
          <li
          *ngFor="let item of airlines"
          class="list-group-item"
          (click)="airlinesClicked($event,item)">
          {{item.name}}           
          </li>
        </ul>
      </ion-row>
```

-----css

```
.search-list{
    z-index: 9;
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```